# Why does the feasible set being a matroid ensure a polynomial time algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, matroids

Reading up on matroid theory in the context of graph optimization and in particular minimum spanning trees. It turns out that finding a set of acyclic arcs is equivalent to finding an independent vector basis of a matrix, which is nice.

In this example, we had a graph consisting of six nodes and nine arcs, which makes a $6\times9$ matrix from which we need to pick out five independent vectors. So there are $9 \choose 5$ potential candidates. What is not clear for me is how this produces a polynomial time algorithm - it seems to me as if all it produces is a possible way of enumerating the elements of the feasible set.

Which of course sounds like brute force, almost by definition. So where does the polynomial time algorithm pop up?

Comment: It might help to specify which book/text you're reading. The fact that a [polynomial time algorithm for MST exists can be proven elementary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Classic_algorithms)...

Comment: I realize you don't need the matroid formulation to prove polynomial complexity, but according to our lecturer, the feasible set being a matroid is a sufficient condition for such an algorithm existing. She actually didn't provide citations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clarifications: when speaking of the(??) feasible set being a matroid, your lecturer was probably talking about greedoids in general. The statement about *the* [feasible set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedoid#Definitions) being a matroid doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but saying that the greedoid (whose feasible set(s) we're talking about) is a matroid does make sense. Furthermore the matroid in this case (graph) is actually a special kind, called [cycle matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedoid#Examples) or [graphic matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_matroid).

For defining something like MST (or anything with weighted graphs), you further need the notion of [weighted matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_matroid). For weighted matroids in general, there is a [polynomial time algorithm for finding a maximum-weight basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Algorithms). And you can use it to find the minimum weight-basis too by "inverting" the weight function, i.e. subtracting it from a large enough constant.

EDIT: Oh, I realized I forgot to tell you anything about the overloading of the term "basis". For a greedoid/matroid, basis [simply means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedoid#Definitions) a maximal feasible/independent set. It's somewhat natural to ask if this choice of terminology is related in any way to the notion of a basis of a vector space (and in particular of a matrix). The answer is yes, in terms of [matroid representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_representation). Briefly:

- The linearly independent subsets of a finite set of vectors form a matroid; that's why a maximal such subset is called a basis.
- If it exists, a representation of a matroid $(E,F)$ is a function $f$ from $F$ to a vector space $V$ such that a subset $A \subseteq E$ is feasible/independent (in the matroid) if and only if $f(A)$ is (linearly) independent (in the vector space). However, not all matroids are representable this way; those which are so are called linear matroids.

Graphic/cycle matroids are all linear though, and in fact are even [regular matroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_matroid), meaning that choice of the field for the vector space does not matter. Furthermore, the [linear matroid defined by the *oriented* incidence matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_matroid#Representation) (interpreted as a set of vectors) of an undirected graph $G$ coincides (is isomorphic with) with the cycle matroid of $G$.

There's a catch here if you try to push this coincidence further to weighted matroids (as to apply it to MST problems): I'm not sure how you can algebraically relate the weighted matroid of a weighted undirected graph to some (unweighted?) matroid of some (weighted?) incidence matrix of that graph. The issue is that on one side the weights get added on top of a "plain" matroid to get a weighted matroid, but on the other side, you'd have a "plain" linear matroid over some real-valued matrix (non just over ${-1, 0, 1}$)... So maybe you should tell us what coefficients you have in your $6\times 9$ matrix.